# "all but one refused to do" means everyone do it or only one did it?

Tags: meaning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“all but at most one” - What does it mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55869/all-but-at-most-one-what-does-it-mean)

When a sentence has this phrase: "....which all but one refused to do."

Does it mean all refused to do and only one did it? Or does it mean everyone did it, except one didn't?

Comment: Also related: [The construction of “Known but to God”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9235/) ◊ [“All but” idiom has two meanings?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9967/) ◊ [Specific usage of the word 'but'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8892/) ◊ [“to have all but X”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9323/) ◊ [“nothing but” vs. “anything but” vs. “everything but”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8061/).

Comment: This plainly isn't a duplicate: *all but at least one* is completely different from *all but one*, which may not be obvious to non-native speakers.  There are, however, sufficient similar questions to make this one not worth re-opening.

Comment: @TimLymington: I'm not sure *all but at least one* really makes sense in any context. The duplicate is for *all but at **most** one*, and the answer there covers the meaning if *"at most"* had been omitted or otherwise failed to apply.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**It means that all refused to do and only one did it.** Sometimes rearranging the structure helps to clarify: "all refused to do [it] but one."

Comment: from the otherways, all but one did means everyone did it but one did not do it.